# Are questions about preparing for industry on topic?

Tags: discussion

Lots of people go to "grad school" to get a job in "industry", where industry might include business (MBA), medicine (MD), and law (JD). Even many who are pursuing a PhD want an industry job afterwards. Are questions about how to use grad school to prepare for an industry job on topic? Has this been discussed already?

Comment: faq of Workplace SE states that "Questions should be about problems you are encountering or have encountered in the workplace, and not the learning/applying of specific job functions." Please see http://workplace.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @scaaahu I removed the comment about workplace.sx. Clearly they are not the right place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that such questions *are* on-topic. However, remember the general principle that your question should not be specific to you: make sure that your formulation allows other people to benefit from your answer. If you have any doubts, you could post a sample version of your question here before sending it to the main board. . . .

Comment: I agree.  I think academia.SE is likely to be one of the best places to find answers for these questions.